# Hoeffding's inequality for random vectors

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ be $n$ i.i.d. samples of a bounded random variable $X \in [a, b]$. We know from the Hoeffding's inequality that :

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \left| \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_n - \mathbb{E}[X] \right| \geq \varepsilon \right) \leq 2 \exp\left( - \frac{2 n \varepsilon^2}{(b-a)^2}\right)$$

Now let $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ be $n$ i.i.d. samples of a bounded random vector $X$. Do we have a similar bound for the following quantity ?

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \left\| \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_n - \mathbb{E}[X] \right\|_1 \geq \varepsilon \right)$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hoeffding's inequality for vector valued random variables](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186097/hoeffdings-inequality-for-vector-valued-random-variables)

Comment: @MarkMeckes Which parts of the linked article give the bounds the OP is looking for?

Comment: @YemonChoi: On closer inspection, it doesn't.

Comment: Theorem 2.1 of this paper yields a bound, though I'm not sure if it's optimal for the $\ell_1$ norm: https://doi.org/10.1016/0047-259X(76)90001-4